# loop keeps printing out same result? (python 3.x) How do I print a loop with different results on each line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When test running use 30 for air temp., and 44 for mph.

This code's loop only generates the same line of code which is this. I want it to be different for each line. How do I do this?

```
    `from math import *

def main():
    tempF = eval (input('Enter air temperature (F): '))
    startingVelocity = eval (input('Enter starting wind speed (mph): '))

    OldStyleWC = round(0.081 * (3.71*sqrt(startingVelocity) + 5.81 - 0.25 * startingVelocity) * (tempF - 91.4) + 91.4,1)
    NewStyleWC = round(35.74 + 0.6215 * tempF - 35.75 * (startingVelocity**0.16) + 0.4275 * tempF * (startingVelocity**0.16),1)
    Difference = round(OldStyleWC - NewStyleWC)

    print (' ')
    print ('Big Blue Wind Chill')
    print (' ')
    print ('Enter air temperature (F): ', startingVelocity)
    print ('Enter starting wind speed (mph): ', tempF)
    print (' ')
    print ('Temperature = ', tempF, 'degrees F')
    print(' ')
    print ('Wind Speed', 'Old Formula', 'New Formula', 'Difference', sep='\t')


    for velocity in range(startingVelocity, 90, 5):

        print(velocity, OldStyleWC, NewStyleWC, Difference, sep="              ")



main()`
```

results from this code:

```
`Wind Speed Old Formula New Formula Difference
44              -5.2              12.4              -18
49              -5.2              12.4              -18
54              -5.2              12.4              -18
59              -5.2              12.4              -18
64              -5.2              12.4              -18
69              -5.2              12.4              -18
74              -5.2              12.4              -18
79              -5.2              12.4              -18
84              -5.2              12.4              -18
89              -5.2              12.4              -18`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from math import *

def main():
    tempF = eval (input('Enter air temperature (F): '))
    startingVelocity = eval (input('Enter starting wind speed (mph): '))

    print (' ')
    print ('Big Blue Wind Chill')
    print (' ')
    print ('Enter air temperature (F): ', startingVelocity)
    print ('Enter starting wind speed (mph): ', tempF)
    print (' ')
    print ('Temperature = ', tempF, 'degrees F')
    print(' ')
    print ('Wind Speed', 'Old Formula', 'New Formula', 'Difference', sep='\t')


    for velocity in range(startingVelocity, 90, 5):
        OldStyleWC = round(0.081 * (3.71*sqrt(velocity) + 5.81 - 0.25 * velocity) * (tempF - 91.4) + 91.4,1)
        NewStyleWC = round(35.74 + 0.6215 * tempF - 35.75 * (velocity**0.16) + 0.4275 * tempF * (velocity**0.16),1)
        Difference = round(OldStyleWC - NewStyleWC)

        print(velocity, OldStyleWC, NewStyleWC, Difference, sep="              ")



main()
```

Comment: The old formula, new formula, and difference are still the same.

Comment: sorry, the `startingVelocity`s should have just been `velocity`s. Edited in.